# How to boost elastic search results based on a field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Query String to query elastic search and below is my sample query.

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "query" : "Sharmila"
    }
}
```

I've field called FLAG in the documents. I want to boost the results if the FLAG== Y. As custom_score is deprecated, I want to use function_score

```
{
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": "Sharmila"
            },
            "functions": [{
                "script_score": {
                    "script": "_score * (doc['FLAG'].value == 'Y' ? 1.2 : 1)"
                }
            }],
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am getting exception saying **No query registered for [script_score]]**

I am using elasticsearch 1.2.2

Any thoughts where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please show your `function_score` query as well.

Comment: I've just added. During the original post, due to indentation problem, I was not able to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to move the `functions` property just below the `function_score` one and not bury it inside your `query`:

```
{
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "functions": [{
            "script_score": {
                "script": "_score * (doc['FLAG'].value == 'Y' ? 1.2 : 1)"
            }
        }],
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": "Sharmila"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome and glad to help!